# Flutter: redirect to the original point after login

Tags: flutter, dart

Need some help on how to route to a new page and then go back to original caller..

In my app, The home page is a list of items. When the user select an item they see the detail with more info button... On some of the items the  user needs to login to see more data.

So, in the above case, I have route to login page and after they have login then I need to redirect back to  same record detail page.

How can I do this in flutter.

This is the code I user to direct them to login screen if the select more info

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)
  .push(CupertinoPageRoute<void>(
     title: "login",
     builder: (BuildContext context) => LoginScreen(),
   ),
);
```

---- Update --

This is my call to login screen but the value return  for "isLoginSuccess"  is always null

```
 _navigateToLogin(applyType) async {
    Future<bool> isLoginSuccess = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => LoginScreen(),
      ),
    );
    isLoginSuccess.then((onValue) {
      if (onValue) {
        _navigateToResumeScreen(applyType);
      }
    });
  }
```

After user login in ..This is pop command to go back to the initial screen

```
 Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
```

The value for

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is many ways you can do it , its depends how is your login flows works , 
here is the simplest way ,

```
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

        class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {


      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('Login'),
                  onPressed: login,
                ),

              ],
            )
          ),
        );
      }

      void login()  {

        // simulate the login 
        Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2)).then((_){

          setState(() {
            // update the UI ,
          });
          // navigate to previous route 
          Navigator.of(context).pop('pass some result back to previus screen');
          // while you pushed to this screen you can a wait the result 
          // coming from this screen 
          // for more info see the navigation in flutter in general 

        });
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks I added additional code snippet for my call but the value return is always null